# PDO: UPDATE not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I wrote some code to update a mySQL table via php/PDO.
But it is not working and I just can't figure out where my mistake is.
The execute() returns true, but the changes never actually show up in the table.

My code looks pretty much like this:

```
$columnObject = array(
    "emailAddress"=>"aaa@aaa.com",
    "passwordHash"=>"56bj5g63j4g57g567g5k75jh7gk4g74j5hg67",
    "name"=>"qweqweqwe",
    "lastActivity"=>4128649814
);
$knownColumnName = "emailAddress";
$knownColumnData = "aaa@aaa.com";

foreach ($columnObject as $columnName => $columnData) {
    $pdoUpdateString .= $columnName . "=:" . $columnName . ",";
    $pdoExecuteObject[$columnName] = $columnData;
}
$pdoUpdateString = rtrim($pdoUpdateString, ",");

$pdoExecuteObject['knownColumn'] = $knownColumnData;
$q = $this->hCon->prepare('UPDATE ' . $this->name . ' SET ' . $pdoUpdateString . ' WHERE ' . $knownColumnName . '=:knownColumn');
$q->execute($pdoExecuteObject);
```

Comment: `echo` out your fields and values that you built in that string then please show us. You may have a formatting error in your query.

Comment: What's the result of `$q->execute($pdoExecuteObject);`? If it returns `false`, please call `print_r($q->errorInfo());` to get more information about the reason of query failure.

Comment: @mario.klump: forivin does mention that "The execute() returns true"... However, @forivin: it may be helpful to see the actual query. For instance: does the row with `'knownColumn' = 'aaa@aaa.com'` really exist?

Comment: @MartenKoetsier You are right. I'm sorry for that. @Forivin Please initialize the variables `$pdoUpdateString` and `$pdoExecuteObject ` to prevent notices in your error log. After that please tell us the result of @Script47 's comment.